# Axios & Redux returns undefined, than resolves

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm creating a system with react & redux  where i need to fetch some data from an api, i made the action/function and reducer but when i try to access the results on my component and console log them it shows undefined three times than resolves, and when i try to map through the results of course i cant because of undefined thing.[enter image description here][1]

Here is my action function code.

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const signIn = () => {
    return {
        type: 'LOGGED'
    };
};

export const getCompaniesAction =  (data)  => {
    return{
        type: "GET_COMPANIES",
        payload: data
    };
};

export function fetchCompanies(){
    return(dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`http://ticketing.mydev.loc/api/companies`, {headers:{
         Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get('access_token')}`
        }}).then(res => res.data.data).then(data => dispatch(getCompaniesAction(data))).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

Here is mu reducer function

```
const companiesReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_COMPANIES':
            return{
                ...state,
                companies: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return{
                ...state
            }
    }
}
export default companiesReducer;
```

Here is the store

```
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
const store = createStore(
    allReducers,  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), composeEnhancer)
)
```

Map state to props

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    companies: state.companiesReducer.companies
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Company);
```

component did mount

```
  componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCompanies()
    }
```

And here i try to access the data

```
   render(){
       if(this.props.companies !== 'undefined'){
           console.log(this.props.companies)
       }
```

So my redux devtool shows perfectly state changes, but this console.log in the component shows undefined three times than shows data.
Thanks for your time <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined is as a result of uninitialized state for `companies`. Also `"undefined"` is a string, not the value `undefined`. Try checking like this

```
render(){
       if(this.props.companies !== undefined){
           console.log(this.props.companies)
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `fetchCompanies` is async, so some stuffs are triggering re-render in your component while your data is being fetched.

You could add a new state and manage it while you are loading data and render a loading message or you could use `componentShouldUpdate` to check yours props and decide if your component should update